# Add one Day at the Date change also the hour

Tags: javascript

I have issue with a date.
I have two date (start and end) and I need to build an array of all date between these two.
My script is something like:

```
while(currentData < nodeLastDate){

    currentData.setDate(currentData.getDate() + 1);

    console.log(currentData)

}
```

But at Sat Mar 30 2019 there is an error and the data change also the time.
if you run this simple script you can see it.

```
let test = new Date(2019, 2, 30, 2)

console.log(test)

test = test.setDate(test.getDate() + 1)

console.log(new Date(test))
```

this is the result:

Sat Mar 30 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale)

index.js?c69d:385 Sun Mar 31 2019 03:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa central)

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

`Date.getDate()` gets the day of the month, so you lose any other information. If you want to add a day to a date, simply use `Date.getTime()` and add the number of milliseconds in a day:

```js
let test = new Date(2019, 2, 30, 2)

console.log(test)

test = test.setDate(test.getTime() + (1440 * 60000))

console.log(new Date(test))
```

`Date.getTime` returns the number of milliseconds since an arbitrary date known as the epoch date, so adding the number of milliseconds in a day will add exactly one day to your date. (1440 * 60000 is the number of milliseconds in a day because there are 1440 minutes in a day and 60000 milliseconds in a minute)

Comment: What you say could be correct but the issue is that the change of hours happens only on Sat Mar 30, 2019, I have analyzed more than 1000 days from 2018-05-11 to 2021-04-29 and every time the .getDate() + 1 works fine.  So, why not on this day?

Comment: @loriswave The other days probably worked because the hour of the day was the default, and thus did’t change when you made a new date. Any other reason would probably just be an artifact of your code, because getTime is the only way to preserve the exact time of a date